# Admin SDK Customer Report API - how to specify a customer domain (as a reseller)

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-reseller-api

I read that the Admin SDK works for Google Apps resellers, but I'm having one specific problem.

I want to use the following request to get the number of user licenses in use on one of my customer's domains.

https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/dates/%s?parameters=accounts:num_users

But there's no way that I can find to specify the customer's domain name that I want to get the usage report for. Tried a few different ways.

There must be a way that is hiding from me because this was possible with the old deprecated API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this API here will do the trick:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/#retrieving_the_current_number_of_users_in_a_domain

Answer (score 0):

Using the Reports API for this is not advisable because it can be delayed by 48+ hours. It's also not possible for reseller users to run reports for customers at this time. Rather, you should use the [Google Apps Reseller API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/) to [list subscription counts](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions/list) that should be fully up to date.

Comment: Hi Jay, the problem with using the Apps Reseller API is that the subscription object does not give you the number of seats in use for FLEXIBLE subscriptions which is what I need to do here.

"flexible plan — For this plan, a reseller is invoiced on the actual number of users which is capped by the maximumNumberOfSeats. The numberOfSeats property is not used in the request or response for flexible plan customers."

So I'm not sure the proper way to find out the numberOfSeats. In the past I used the old deprecated API.